# How do configure Azure Active Directory for SSO?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

for a client, I need to set up Azure Active Directory because he wants his employees and customers to log in through Microsoft SSO. I have no experience with AD at all and I'm a bit overwhelmed by the documentation. The "customers" are all B2B clients, so no personal accounts. It's a TypeScript project.

Please let me also know if this thinking is correct:
"The client wants his employees and external companies to be able to sign in, therefore I need to use a Multitenant application, if he wants to add the users that have access manually, he can use a single tenant."

We would also need a way to read the groups, that the user, that is logging in through SSO, is in. We use the groups to assign them roles later on.

So the user should be able to log in through their Microsoft Accounts and allow us to read the groups they are in.

We then take the access token and the id token and send them to our backend, where we fetch the user's groups.

I set up two different Active Directory applications, one for Single tenants, and one for Multitenant (without personal Accounts).

I then set it up to allow Access tokens and id tokens in Authentication, I added some Token claims to get the email and I added API permissions for `Group.Read.All` and
`GroupMember.Read.All`. I have a dummy front end that allows me to log in and gives me the access token and id token.

When I log in to the single tenant application, everything works fine, I can log in with users that exist in my tenant and I get what I need without it asking me for admin consent.

When I try the same thing with my multitenant, I use the same settings as the single tenant app (but configured for multitenant and my frontend is using

`authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/",`

so "organizations" instead of a tenant id, and I try to sign in with a user outside of my Active Directory users, it asks me for Admin consent.

How do I avoid it asking me for consent?
Is this the right kind of setup or do I need to do something different?

Thank you very much!

[image: These are the permissions I added to the API]

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure but if you (admin) already consent it once, would the consent appear again when sign in next time?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, I can't give admin consent for them when they log in because they are external users that just want to use MS SSO to sign in to the application, I don't know them. But I granted the Admin consent in the API permissions tab.

Comment: Could you attach a snip of the consent?

Comment: I added a screenshot :) these are the API permissions I used and when I try to log in it asks me for admin consent but only for external users that are not in the directory.

Comment: What do you mean by "admin consent snip"? On login I get redirected to a Microsoft Pop Up that asks me to log in as the administrator to grant access.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the error like below:***

[image]

I created an **Azure AD Multi-Tenant Application** and granted consent for API permissions:

[image]

Now, I tried to **grant tenant wide admin consent** by using below URL and logging in as Global Admin:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/adminconsent?client_id=ClientID
```

[image]

Try allowing the users to consent to the Application like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Enterprise Application -> User Settings -> Go to Consent and permissions*

[image]

Make sure to that below option is set to **No** in Enterprise Application Users settings:

[image]

After the above setting **I am able to login to the Application with another tenant user successfully** like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query  
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

[image]

**Reference:**

[Azure AD app consent experiences - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/application-consent-experience)